# Restricting Places API in Wordrpess Address Lookup

Tags: wordpress, google-api, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have a simple address lookup or autocomplete as part of a Wordpress site
https://diversechurch.co.nz/find_a_church/submit-a-church/

I want to know if it is possible to restrict the lookup results to one country (NZ) and how do to this?

I am only a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following link from Google api document

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#optional-parameters